# How to mock 'universal-cookie' in jest/enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, cookies, jestjs, enzyme

I have a React component that uses 'universal-cookie'. On calling mount in test cases the cookies object is empty.

```
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
const cookies = new Cookies();
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
   componentDidMount(){
     axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = cookies.get('token').value; //12492525
   }
}

//My Test File
describe('MyComponent Test', () => {
  it('Component mounted', () => {
     const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent/>);
  });
});
```

When I run my test file I keep getting the error

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined" near cookies.

Cookies value is empty no matter how many times I try to mock or set it.

So far I tried setting

```
cookies.set('HAS_DOCUMENT_COOKIE', true);
cookies.set('token', { value: '1244'});// in my test file
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [jest.mock(moduleName, factory, options)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) mock `universal-cookie` and `axios` modules

E.g.
`index.tsx`:

```js
import React from "react";
import Cookies from "universal-cookie";
import axios from "axios";

const cookies = new Cookies();

export class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = cookies.get("token").value; //12492525
    console.log(axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization);
  }
  render() {
    return null;
  }
}
```

`index.spec.tsx`:

```js
import React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import Cookies from "universal-cookie";
import axios from "axios";
import { MyComponent } from "./";

jest.mock("axios", () => {
  return {
    defaults: {
      headers: {
        common: {
          Authorization: ""
        }
      }
    }
  };
});

jest.mock("universal-cookie", () => {
  const mCookie = {
    get: jest.fn()
  };
  return jest.fn(() => mCookie);
});

describe("MyComponent", () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
  it("should set token correctly", () => {
    const cookies = new Cookies();
    (cookies.get as jest.Mocked<any>).mockReturnValueOnce({
      value: "12492525"
    });
    const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, "log");
    const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent></MyComponent>);
    expect(axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization).toBe("12492525");
    expect(logSpy).toBeCalledWith("12492525");
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
PASS  src/stackoverflow/59146770/index.spec.tsx (9.453s)
  MyComponent
    ✓ should set token correctly (21ms)

  console.log node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:860
    12492525

-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File       |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files  |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.tsx |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.887s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/59146770

Comment: The scope of the `universal-cookie` mock is important.  Inside the `describe` it did not work for us.